# Viewport view goes into pivot mode after applying rotation or scale

Tags: 3d-view, transforms, navigation, keymap

When I change scale or rotation, or move a vertex, I use a single LMB click or press enter to apply the change. The viewport immediately goes into a pivot mode, rotating my view around the object or vertex, and only exits the pivot view when I click a second time. It's very annoying because I lose the perspective where I was looking from, and takes twice as long to make changes in vertices. I don't recall this being an issue before, applying a change was completed with a single click.  I'm in Blender 3.6 on a windows laptop. I've searched far and wide for what's probably a simple tick box, but I don't get it, thanks in advance if anyone can help!

Here's a shot of my navigation settings.

[image: screenshot of navigation settings in blender]

Comment: I don't know what's causing your problem, but for what it's worth I have Orbit Around Selection, Auto > Perspective and Depth and Zoom to Mouse Position all checked on my settings.